# Ocean oscillations with long time periods

Tags: climate, oceanography, paleoclimatology, ocean-currents, ocean-models

I heard that some ocean oscillations act on a time scale of a millennium. Is this true, or at least argued by some oceanographers? If so, what are they and what causes them? If not, what are the largest time scale ocean oscillations

Edit: After some research, I believe I may be looking for "Atlantic meridional overturning circulation" (AMOC). However, I haven't been able to understand so far if it is a true oscillation with 1000 year period. Can anyone conform if this is so? Or is it rather that it has changed over this timescale but not necessarily following an oscillation pattern?

Thank you

Comment: what type of oscillations are you talking about,El Niño ?, amoc?.

Comment: I have in mind any process that happens in the oceans on a cyclic basis where the cycle length is much longer than annual

Comment: @PeterA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_decadal_oscillation is an obvious candidate isn't it ?

Comment: Yes this is just the kind of thing I am looking for, but on much longer time scale. The specific quote I am trying to verify is there are some oscillations on the scale of 1000 years

Comment: I believe what I am looking for may be "Atlantic meridional overturning circulation". Will update the question